When i run a default maui blazor app it not showing output. Whats the reason for that?
Windows 10 pro
version 22h2
os biuld 19045.4291
Visual Studio enterprise 2022 17.9.6
This is my pc and visual studio versions that im using.
When i run a default maui blazor app it not showing output
Whats the reason for that?
this is the error message i got
The program '[12180] MauiApp2.exe' has exited with code 2147942405 (0x80070005).
I run as admin and run it not gave output and repair visualstudio and tried didnt gave. I have to get the output page of the default app

To help fix the issue, May I know which version of Maui does this occur on? Also the target platforms? Does this affect only Blazor or all Maui apps?

Please try the workarounds below to migitate the issue:

Add the project property in the csproj file of your MAUI Blazor app:

<PropertyGroup>
   <WindowsAppSdkDeploymentManagerInitialize>
false</WindowsAppSdkDeploymentManagerInitialize>
</PropertyGroup>


Manually install the latest Windows App SDK runtime.

This issue is related with MAUI apps crash on launch on Windows after Visual Studio update - code 2147942405 (0x80070005) #12080
